# Modal View Controller transitions

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, modalviewcontroller

I'm trying to do some fanciful transitions for my iPad application. I'm using this presentModalViewController to show another view.

But the only available transitions are:

```
modelViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
modelViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
modelViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
modelViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
```

Are there any ways that i can have some cool or maybe 3D transitions?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [QuartzCore framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/QuartzCoreRefCollection/_index.html) or using [animation blocks](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Basic_iOS_4_iPhone_Animation_using_Core_Animation#UIView_Core_Animation_Blocks). The first one is the hard way, the second one is easier but limited.